# Problem when applying FindRoot to a very complicated function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

The error I get when evaluating my code is:

FindRoot: The function value [...] is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {q}={2.25}.

I have read a lot of questions regarding this error, though none of the solutions provided have worked for me, but maybe I'm just implementing them wrongly. Here is the code:

```
f1 = 9*q^2*r0 - q^2*Sqrt[81*r0^2 - 12*q^2]
f2 = 9*q^2*r0 + q^2*Sqrt[81*r0^2 - 12*q^2]
r2 = (1/144^(1/3))[(f1^(1/3) + f2^(1/3)) + I*Sqrt[3]*(f1^(1/3) - f2^(1/3))]
r3 = (1/144^(1/3))[(f1^(1/3) + f2^(1/3)) - I*Sqrt[3]*(f1^(1/3) - f2^(1/3))]
a = (2*r2 + r3)/(r2 + 2*r3)
b = r2/(2*r2 + r3)
\[Phi][r_, r0_, q_] = (1/Sqrt[r2*(r2 + 2*r3)])*2*q*(EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[(b*(r + r2 + r3))/r]], (r2/r3)*a] - EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[b]], (r2/r3)*a])
FindRoot[\[Phi][1, 1, q] == Pi, {q, 2.25}]
```

The original problem would be to find a solution for $q$(as a function of $r_0$) when $r=r_0$, so $$\phi(r_0,r_0,q)=\pi$$ but since that wasn't working I tried to solve the simpler problem $$\phi(1,1,q)=\pi.$$

What I hope is that by finding out how to fix this simpler case I could also solve the more general one.

The general solution should be $q=2.22864*r_0$

Note that $r$,$r_0$ and $q$ are real, and $r$, $r_0$ are also positive.

Some additional information: the definition I gave of $r_2$ and $r_3$ depends on the values of $q$ and $r_0$ since they come from the roots of a cubic equation.

For $\lvert q/r_0 \rvert < 3\sqrt{3}/2$ my definition holds, and this is where the solution i'm looking for is.

For $\lvert q/r_0 \rvert > 3\sqrt{3}/2$, $r_2$ and $r_3$ are real and can be defined as

```
r2 = ((2*Abs[q])/Sqrt[3])*Cos[(1/3)*ArcCos[(-3*Sqrt[3]*r0)/(2*Abs[q])]]
r3 = (Abs[q]/Sqrt[3])*(-Cos[(1/3)*ArcCos[(-3*Sqrt[3]*r0)/(2*Abs[q])]] + 
Sqrt[3]*Sin[(1/3)*ArcCos[(-3*Sqrt[3]*r0)/(2*Abs[q])]])
```

I tried also using this definition, just because, and I don't get the same error if I use the option

```
FindRoot[\[Phi][1, 1, q] == Pi, {q, 2.25}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]
```

But the results it gives are nonsense(it gives another type of error), since of course the solution is not in the interval where $r_2$ and $r_3$ are defined.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Your expressions for `r2` and `r3` include `[` and `]` instead of `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
f1 = 9*q^2*r0 - q^2*Sqrt[81*r0^2 - 12*q^2]
f2 = 9*q^2*r0 + q^2*Sqrt[81*r0^2 - 12*q^2]
r2 = (1/144^(1/3))*((f1^(1/3) + f2^(1/3)) + 
    I*Sqrt[3]*(f1^(1/3) - f2^(1/3)))
r3 = (1/144^(1/3))*((f1^(1/3) + f2^(1/3)) - 
    I*Sqrt[3]*(f1^(1/3) - f2^(1/3)))
a = (2*r2 + r3)/(r2 + 2*r3)
b = r2/(2*r2 + r3)
\[Phi][r_, r0_, q_] = (1/Sqrt[r2*(r2 + 2*r3)])*2*
  q*(EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[(b*(r + r2 + r3))/r]], (r2/r3)*a] - 
    EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[b]], (r2/r3)*a])
FindRoot[\[Phi][1, 1, q] == Pi, {q, 2.25}]

{q -> 3.9041 + 1.4084 I}
```

You can not use [] as braces. Use ().

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, that solved my problem